Autocompletion doesn't work and other quirks while setting up AUCTeX with use-package
I've been using Emacs + Spacemacs for writing my LaTeX documents (and some programming) for a long while. As a project for this weekend I'm trying to dig deeper into Emacs fundamentals and write my own init.el.
I started by configuring straight.el and use-package. Other packages I installed are company for autocompletion, helm, and finally AUCTeX.
At this point my init.el looks like this. This is the code for setting up MELPA:
;; MELPA (see https://melpa.org/)

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
;; Comment/uncomment this line to enable MELPA Stable if desired.  See `package-archive-priorities`
;; and `package-pinned-packages`. Most users will not need or want to do this.
;;(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

This is the code for setting up straight.el and use-package:
;; straight.el (see https://github.com/radian-software/straight.el)

(defvar bootstrap-version)
(let ((bootstrap-file
       (expand-file-name
        "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el"
        (or (bound-and-true-p straight-base-dir)
            user-emacs-directory)))
      (bootstrap-version 7))
  (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
    (with-current-buffer
        (url-retrieve-synchronously
         "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radian-software/straight.el/develop/install.el"
         'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (eval-print-last-sexp)))
  (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))

;; use-package (see https://github.com/radian-software/straight.el)
(straight-use-package 'use-package)

This is the code for company-mode and helm:
;; company-mode

(use-package company
  :straight t
  :hook (progr-mode-hook . company-mode)
  ;:config (setq company-backends '((company-capf company-dabbrev-code))) ; I don't know what it does
  )

;; helm

(use-package helm
  :straight t
  :config
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-x") #'helm-M-x)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-x r b") #'helm-filtered-bookmarks)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") #'helm-find-files)
  (helm-mode 1)
  )

Ans finally here's the code for AUCTeX:
;; AUCTeX

(use-package auctex
  :straight t)

(setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load.
(setq TeX-auto-save t) ; Enable parse on save.
(setq-default TeX-master nil) ; I don't know what it does

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'LaTeX-math-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'flyspell-mode)


I don't understand

why does autocompletion never show up when I'm editing a .tex;
why does Emacs complain if I write something like the snippet below and why doesn't the hooks I declared work properly

;; AUCTeX

(use-package auctex
  :straight t
  :hook (
         (LaTeX-mode-hook . LaTeX-math-mode)
         (LaTeX-mode-hook . flyspell-mode)
    )
  :config (
           (setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load.
           (setq TeX-auto-save t) ; Enable parse on save.
           (setq-default TeX-master nil) ; I don't know what it does
    )
  )


how to make Emacs behave more like some sort of an IDE (I would like Emacs to point me at errors I make when I'm writing LaTeX code, to provide me autocomplete options when I start writing \begin{t, etc. Does AUCTeX provide this functionality itself and I have not been able to enable it yet?)


Before getting to AUCTeX, there are some comments about the code snippets you sent.  First, I suppose progr-mode-hook is a typo and you meant prog-mode-hook.  Next, when setting hooks with use-package, you have to drop the -hook from the hook-name, so your company part becomes:
;; company-mode

(use-package company
  :straight t
  :hook
  (prog-mode . company-mode))

This is a documented feature.
Next, you can set global key-bindings with the :bind keyword, so your helm part becomes:
(use-package helm
  :straight t
  :init
  (helm-mode 1)
  :bind
  (("M-x" . helm-M-x)
   ("C-x r b" . helm-filtered-bookmarks)))

This is also a documented feature.
To your AUCTeX questions:
Why does autocompletion never show up when I'm editing a .tex
Maybe because you don't activate company-mode in LaTeX-mode; LaTeX-mode derives from text-mode, and not from prog-mode.  Try this:
;; company-mode

(use-package company
  :straight t
  :hook
  ((prog-mode LaTeX-mode) . company-mode))

Why does Emacs complain if I write something like the snippet below and why doesn't the hooks I declared work properly
See above, it should read:
(use-package auctex
  :straight t
  :hook
  ((LaTeX-mode . LaTeX-math-mode)
   (LaTeX-mode . flyspell-mode))
  :config 
  (setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load.
  (setq TeX-auto-save t) ; Enable parse on save.
  (setq-default TeX-master nil) ; I don't know what it does
  )

How to make Emacs behave more like some sort of an IDE (I would like Emacs to point me at errors I make when I'm writing LaTeX code
You can activate flycheck-mode which does this with an external program, chktex for example.  The code above would bec
(use-package auctex
  :straight t
  :hook
  ((LaTeX-mode . LaTeX-math-mode)
   (LaTeX-mode . flyspell-mode)
   (LaTeX-mode . flycheck-mode))
  :config 
  (setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load.
  (setq TeX-auto-save t) ; Enable parse on save.
  (setq-default TeX-master nil) ; I don't know what it does
  )

This is also a documented feature.
Provide me autocomplete options when I start writing \begin{t, etc. Does AUCTeX provide this functionality itself and I have not been able to enable it yet?
AUCTeX doesn't provide the completion you're asking above.  OOTB, environments are included via C-c C-e.  AUCTeX provides in-buffer completion for macros like this:

and their arguments where applicable:

or arguments of environments like this:


Apparently the solution to the last problem was to put
(setq TeX-parse-self t), (setq TeX-auto-save t) and (setq-default TeX-master nil) inside (with-eval-after-load 'tex [...]).
